# Laravel localization middleware takes a long time to determine current language and times out

Tags: laravel

So, I have a bit of a weird issue. I have a localization middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use URL;

class setLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->segment(1)]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This is included in the kernel like so.

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
  ------->  \App\Http\Middleware\setLocale::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

        ],
};
```

Then in my `web.php` file I have some routes that are localized

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});

Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}']], static function () {
    Route::get('/', static function () {
        return view('auth.login');
    })->name("home");

    Route::get('/register', static function () {
        return view('auth.register');
    })->name("signup");
});
```

When a fresh user comes the the website they wil hit the `/` route, this takes a loooong time to determine the users locale, it times out due to too many redirects and 1 second after it redirects to the correct locale.

Any reason why it times out, and then redirects to the correct locale anyway ?

Comment: " too many redirects" it feels like this is the root of your problem. Where is it doing multiple redirects, and why? Is your localization middleware causing those redirects? You could gauge this by disabling it and seeing if they still happen. You may also get a lot of information about why this is happening by opening the network tab in chrome debug tools and checking 'preserve log' so that redirects don't clear the history.

Comment: Just did some testing and it indeed seems to be the middlware, using chrome devtools and checking the network tab. whole bunch of 302s then a 500 and after a few seconds another 302 to the correct locale